# What are these 2 for statements doing in this python list?

Tags: python

So I came across this algorithm in Python that generates a list containing lists of unique permutations, given a list that may or may not contain duplicate integers.

```
nums = [1, 2, 1]
def generateUniquePermutations(self, nums):
    perms = [[]]
    for n in nums:
        perms = [p[:i] + [n] + p[i:]
                 for p in perms
                 for i in xrange((p + [n]).index(n) + 1)]
    return perms
```

I don't understand the syntax of the `for p` and `for i` loops embedded in the `perms` list or what they are intended to do, especially since they follow the statement `p[:i] + [n] + p[i:]` which generates a path.  Is the `for i` considered `nested` under the `for p` in this case?  It sort of looks like it is.

Comment: This is a _list comprehension_

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @Nona, it is a list comprehension. Briefly speaking a list comprehension is a declarative way to create a list in Python.

Comment: It's worth noting that this looks odd at first glance because the list comprehension is split across multiple lines. It's perfectly valid to do this, but you typically see them all in one line

Answer (score 1):

This a list comprehension. It generates a list.
An example of this would be:

```py
squares = [x ** 2 for x in range(4)]
#[0, 1, 4, 9]
## Equivalent To:
squares = []
for x in range(4):
    squares.append(x ** 2)
#[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

All on one line it is this:

```py
perms = [p[:i] + [n] + p[i:] for p in perms for i in xrange((p + [n]).index(n) + 1)]
```

The longer / expanded way of doing this:

```py
newPerms = []
for i in xrange((p + [n]).index(n) + 1)
   for p in perms:
       newPerms.append(p[:i] + [n] + p[i:])
perms = newPerms
```